# I have bug in navigation in my app, while moving to more than 2 screens?

Tags: flutter

I have a bug in navigation in my app, while moving to more than 2 screens, when I move to B from A screen then I move to C screen from B, and when I press back from C Screen then I comes to Screen A, it should come to B, any help will be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: Please share the code from your method where you navigate back from screen C.

Comment: `code` Navigator.push(
                                            context,
                                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                                builder: (context) =>
                                                    ImageViewFullScreen(
                                                      url: url,
                                                      key: GlobalKey(),
                                                    ),
                                                maintainState: true));

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the concepts of Push and Pop in Flutter when Navigating through pages.

You have to see this:

https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Comment: hello muhammad nooman, i think you not read the description carefully, i done many push and pop, the problem is each screen has listview, when press on the item i will navigate to another screen, on the last screen when i press back then i will navigate to the first screen, this should not be happen actually. i need to go back to immediate screen.

Comment: you didn't say anything regarding push and pop in your question neither you said that it is redirecting on listItem click. Well, this issue can easily resolved with push and pop techniques